# can a struct implementing Deref return a reference to external data?

Tags: rust

I have an `Idx` struct which is logically a reference to some other data structure, where that other data structure outlives the `Idx`. I'd like `Idx` to deref to something contained in that external data structure, but afaict that's not possible because I would need to implement `deref` with the type

```
struct Idx<'a>(&'a Foo, usize);

impl<'a> Deref for Idx<'a> {
  fn deref<'b: 'a>(&'b self) -> &'a Self::Target { todo!() }
}
```

which doesn't match the definition in the stdlib (and Deref is a langitem(?) so I can't write a more general version myself)

playground with error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=080dddf8854f5928dfc35f6526f57c3e

```
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Foo {
    xs: Vec<u8>,
}

struct Idx<'a>(&'a Foo, usize);

impl<'a> Deref for Idx<'a> {
    type Target = u8;
    fn deref(&self) -> &u8 {
        &self.0.xs[self.1]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        xs: vec!(10, 11, 12),
    };
    let mut xs_refs: Vec<&u8> = vec!();
    for i in 0..3 {
       let idx = Idx(&foo, i);
       xs_refs.push(&*idx);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to tie the `Deref` output lifetime to some lifetime outside your type. You'll have to just add a getter function to `Idx`.

Comment: `Deref` was designed with smart pointers in mind, that is a data structure that owns its content allowing access to that content transparently. It's ill-suited for other uses that aren't smart pointers or very simple newtypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you indeed cannot change `Deref`.

Usually in this case you `Deref` but also have a method that returns the reference with the full lifetime ([this is what e.g. `Pin` does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.get_ref)). This way, you can use `Deref` to invoke methods conventionally, but still have the possibility to use the longer-lived reference when needed.